# Problem reading system file in Android app, even with root

Tags: android

I am writing an app to monitor some files under /sys/devices/.../cpu.  There is one file that is owned by root:root, with only read permissions for root.

I added code to exec("su"), but even then I get a file not found exception.  The only way I don't get an error is if I chmod the file permissions.  However, these permissions get set back to root read after boot, so I'd really like to find how to do the read without changing the file perms.

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Can you use exec to su then chmod the file permissions from within the app?

Comment: I will try that, but the thing that I don't understand is WHY doesn't what I did work?  Also, this seems like a kind of inelegant way?  How do appear like root explorer do stuff like this... do they also exec chmods?

Comment: can't seem to get this working.  I can exec the "su", but then the chmod fails with an exitValue of 10.  I kind of feel that the su may be making one PID run under root, but then the chmod is a different process.

Comment: chmodding and messing with files under /sys/ is almost certainly a VERY bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this following the code here: http://code.google.com/p/market-enabler/source/browse/branches/MarketAccess/src/ru/org/amip/MarketAccess/utils/ShellInterface.java.  Jim